# Different color for each bullet point

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make each bullet in an UL have a different color like in this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4J3T.jpg

I thought possibly using nth-child for each item, but I apply the bullet with the before pseudo element. From my understanding you can't stack pseudo elements. Any ideas?

You can see my code here: http://sacredheart.silverfishdevelopment.com

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: image does not load. Also you need to put the code in your question we are not going to visit your site to test it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how many bullet points you have you will add more nth-child tags with your colors.  For this example I just used RGB.

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li><span>first</span></li>
  <li><span>second</span></li>
  <li><span>third</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li {
  float: left;
  margin: 25px;
}
li:nth-child(1) {
  color: red;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  color: blue;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  color: green;
}
li span {
  color: black;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2eptc5vt/

Comment: You'd have to add ::before here, otherwise the text colour will change.
'li:nth-child(n)::before' is perfectly valid markup.

Comment: I was just saying if he didn't want to deal with adding the bullet points with  ::before, he can use my example.

Answer (score 0):

> From my understanding you can't stack pseudo elements

You can.

```
.topMenuLowerSiteMenu li:nth-child(1)::before {
    color: red;
}

.topMenuLowerSiteMenu li:nth-child(2)::before {
    color: green;
}

.topMenuLowerSiteMenu li:nth-child(3)::before {
    color: blue;
}
```

... etc

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use this format:

```
li:nth-child(1):before {
  color: red;
}
```

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

li:before {
  content: '•';
}

li:nth-child(1):before {
  color: red;
}

li:nth-child(2):before {
  color: blue;
}

li:nth-child(3):before {
  color: yellow;
}

li:nth-child(4):before {
  color: green;
}

li:nth-child(5):before {
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>ONE</li>
  <li>TWO</li>
  <li>THREE</li>
  <li>FOUR</li>
  <li>FIVE</li>
</ul>
```